# Use Git as an undo-redo manager?

Tags: git, undo-redo

I'm trying to use Git as an undo-redo manager for changes made to a directory.

I essentially want the following:

- **An undo command**, that resets the contents of the directory to the state of the previous commit (only if there was a previous commit)

  ```
  State
  -----
   -> * 3b1e4d8 F
      * fb2c608 E
      * cdd8ac5 D
      * aefe3ee C
      * 458bb4f B
      * 17fa95e A
  currently "active" commit: F  (represented by ->)


  Undo
  ----

      * 3b1e4d8 F
   -> * fb2c608 E
      * cdd8ac5 D
      * aefe3ee C
      * 458bb4f B
      * 17fa95e A

  Note that F is still visible and not lost

  Undo
  ----

      * 3b1e4d8 F
      * fb2c608 E
   -> * cdd8ac5 D
      * aefe3ee C
      * 458bb4f B
      * 17fa95e A
  ```
- **A redo command**, which undo's the undo, that is, resets the contents of the directory to the state of the next commit.

  ```
  Redo
  ----

      * 3b1e4d8 F
   -> * fb2c608 E
      * cdd8ac5 D
      * aefe3ee C
      * 458bb4f B
      * 17fa95e A
  ```
- **No commits should be lost**. That is, no commits should become "dangling", and must always be reachable, and must always show up in git log.

  ```
  Change G
  ----

   -> * f12ea02 G
      |  * 3b1e4d8 F
      | /
      * fb2c608 E
      * cdd8ac5 D
      * aefe3ee C
      * 458bb4f B
      * 17fa95e A

  Note that the commit F is not lost from history/log
  ```
- **Ability to push and pull the repo from a remote.**

How do I accomplish this behavior?

---

I can implement undo using `reset HEAD^`, but that causes the latest commit to be lost. (The latest commit can still be reached by the commit hash, but the `git log` doesn't show it, and pushing the repo causes the commit to be lost forever).
So, that doesn't work.

I can instead got a `checkout HEAD^` for undo, but now I'm in a detached head state and can't push to remote. Also, if I make any changes from a detached head state, the branch doesn't follow the head.

Comment: If you undo with checkout and make a branch, you are no longer detached. And nothing is lost so long as a branch or tag name points to it or its descendant. It’s just a question of making sure every needed commit is reachable by a name. Really it’s hard to see how what you want to do here differs from “use git” in general. Git is exactly an undo redo manager.

Comment: You just need to add branches or tags or other names or references that keep those commits alive. In your last example there, you "just" need to make sure you have names that refer to F and G respectively. If no name, or other reference, refers to F then yes, that is a "dangling" commit.

Comment: @NitsanAvni not just a thought experiment - I did implement it. It is simpler than it sounds and just requires one to understand how git internally works. Still, I've realized that Git is perhaps not the best tool for what I was trying to accomplish, so I've a custom VCS now (which only works with my usecase, and is in no way generic and "good")

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all, pushing after a reset does not mean that the commit is "lost forever'.  You may feel this is beside the point, because there are other reasons why simply resetting won't behave as you want in general, but it you want to devise your own use cases for git, you need to start by having a correct conceptual knowledge of how it manages information.

And, as you have noticed, there aren't simple git commands that map to your "undo' and "redo" operations - because what you describe is not what git was designed to do.  That doesn't mean it can't do it - it's very flexible.  But it does mean that you're trying to devise your own use case.

So there's not a simple solution.  You're going to have to design through the edge cases, and the cases you've glossed over (when you've diverged after an undo, you've said you want the old state you undid to still be reachable and visible - but how do you want it shown, and how do you want to refer to it?

And once you've done that design work, you'll have to build the software to implement it.  Maybe you'll find git's functionality to provide a good foundation for that, in which case you can write scripts that string together git commands.  But it won't just be "run this one command", and it will probably involve commands that are less commonly used by end users (plumbing commands).

As is hopefully clear by now, a detailed step-by-step answer is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow Q&A.  So that brings me back to the beginning - you need to begin by having a detailed understanding of how git handles the data you commit to it.  If you have specific questions along those lines, and if the (pretty good, albeit sometimes poorly-phrased) git documentation does not clarify matters, you then might have a question we can reasonably answer.